# Display two different JSON results in one line

Tags: python, json, google-places-api, google-distancematrix-api

I am new to JSON, Google Maps APIs DistanceMatrix & Places 
I am trying to display results from two different JSON Results

Basically both of them come from two different "lists"

**edit** 
for `object_json` i am getting all the nearby places from my coordinates, I will then get the places_id of each result and use it to query the distance-matrix api and get each of distances `object_json2`

**Code**

```
    #name and types from Places API
    lines = (f"{s['name']}: {', '.join(r.replace('_', ' ') for r in s['types'])} -" for s in object_json['results'][0:5])
    #distance from DistanceMatrix API
    lines2 = (f"{t['distance']['text']}" for t in item['elements'] for item in object_json2['rows'])
```

Sample JSON
object_json: getting the name, types and places_id

```
   "results" : [
      {
         "name" : "Joe’s Thai Kitchen",
         "place_id" : "ChIJIadbw8sb2jER3i-OvZSCBGk",
         "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
      },
```

object_json2 based on the nearby search results, it will get the places_id and get the distance matrix results for each elements distance.

```
"rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "0.3 km",
                  "value" : 303
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "2 mins",
                  "value" : 123
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "90 m",
                  "value" : 90
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "1 min",
                  "value" : 36
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
```

**First two results**

```
Joe’s Thai Kitchen: restaurant, food, point of interest, establishment - ['0.4 km', '77 m', '0.3 km', '0.8 km', '0.3 km']

Hong Kong Street Chun Kee: restaurant, food, point of interest, establishment - ['0.4 km', '77 m', '0.3 km', '0.8 km', '0.3 km']
```

**Desired first two results**

```
Joe’s Thai Kitchen: restaurant, food, point of interest, establishment - 0.4 km
Hong Kong Street Chun Kee: restaurant, food, point of interest, establishment - 77 m
```

Hope somebody can help thank you.

Comment: Add a sample of `object_json2` and `object_json`. They would look like [Distance Matrix Responses](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#DistanceMatrixResponses) but we don't know what your initial requests/queries were. Under `rows`, what is your criteria for which `elements` you want to use for the distances? (Since you're not using the remainder.) Is it just the first distance element of the first result?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. That first code snippet really needs some refactoring.

Comment: @aneroid thanks for your reply. I added the same of the `object_json` and `object_json2` results. Basically I want to get every distance under the elements because it is all the nearby search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I don't think you're interpreting the results from the Distance Maxtrix API correctly. This is also leading to [the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/193893).

But in any case, what you're actually looking to do is join the results of two lists in `object1` and `object2`. You can do this with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). `zip()` takes each iterable given and returns a tuple of each lists' n<sup>th</sup> element. And stops at the shortest one:

```
>>> list(zip('ABCD', 'xyz'))
[('A', 'x'), ('B', 'y'), ('C', 'z')]
```

Assuming `object_json` looks like this:

```
object_json = {
    "results" : [
        {
            "name" : "Joe’s Thai Kitchen",
            "place_id" : "ChIJIadbw8sb2jER3i-OvZSCBGk",
            "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
        },
        {
            "name" : "Hong Kong Street Chun Kee",
            "place_id" : "KgbcszVo-I3reJ2BS8WBDAijiHc",
            "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
        }
    ]
}
```

Using `object_json2` as per your example:

```
>>> lines = (f"{s['name']}: {', '.join(r.replace('_', ' ') for r in s['types'])} -" for s in object_json['results'][0:5])
>>> lines2 = (f"{t['distance']['text']}" for item in object_json2['rows'] for t in item['elements'])
>>>
>>> [' '.join((x, y)) for x, y in zip(lines, lines2)]
['Joe’s Thai Kitchen: restaurant, food, point of interest, establishment - 0.3 km',
 'Hong Kong Street Chun Kee: restaurant, food, point of interest, establishment - 90m'
]
```

*(Btw, in your code this line  is a syntax error: `lines2 = (f"{t['distance']['text']}" for t in item['elements'] for item in object_json2['rows'])`.
The 2nd for loop should come first.)*

Comment: Thank you for your help that did the trick. I added `lines3 = *4th line* str1 = '\n\n'.join(lines3)` to convert it to string and display it accordingly. Apologies for the error on the code but thank you for correcting me! Again thanks for your help